# AngularJS\TypeScript Simple Controller connection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to use TypeScript in AngularJS development. I am new and just trying to get some basic building blocks. I started with this tutorial: http://angularfirst.com/your-first-angular-project-in-visual-studio/

After getting it to work I tried to convert it to TypeScript and this is where I have not been able to make the connection.

What I am trying to do is to create a TypeScript class that can be used as a controller, currently I am just using a simple property bag. Once I understand how to get the class to be read then I will expand my controller.

My class looks like this:

```
class main {
    "use strict";
    public food: string;
    constructor() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.food = "pizza";
    }
}
```

My controller call looks like this:

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("Main",
        ["$scope", main]);
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>
<body ng-controller="Main as vm">

    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.food" placeholder="Enter food" />

    <p ng-show="food">Sriracha sauce is great with {{vm.food}}!</p>

    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.module.js"></script>
    <script src="app/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

My result is:

```
Sriracha sauce is great with {{vm.food}}!
```

What I expect is:

```
Sriracha sauce is great with pizza!
```

I have tried passing $scope into the constructor and have tried to understand what the $inject does but have not gotten this to work.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am stuck and have not been able to locate an answer or example in a couple nights of search and play.

Thanks

EDIT:
I have tried the comments from Kim and basarat singularly and together and neither solution changed the results.

I tried debugging in Chrome and it is not hitting the constructor.

After working through the examples and trying a few of my own thoughts and changes here is what I have.

```
class main {
"use strict";
public food: string;
constructor() {
    this.food = "pizza";
    //$scope.vm = this;

}
}


(function() {

angular
    .module("app",[])
    .controller("Main", function ($scope) {
        $scope.vm = new main();
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you try: angular.module("app",[])?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not properly construct your module.
It should have [] such that:

```
angular.module("app", []).controller("Main", function ($scope) {
     $scope.vm = new main();
});
```

Also, you need to pass a function in the controller instead of your class. Inside your scope, you instantiate your class.

Comment: He also doesn't actually call that function.

Answer (score 0):

Put the current instance on the `$scope` :

```
class main {
    "use strict";
    public food: string;
    constructor($scope) {
        $scope.vm = this;
        this.food = "pizza";
    }
}
```